# Android layout: merge into LinearLayout not showing all fields

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom view with layout that I am trying to optimize by removing redundant LinearLayout layers.

My custom layout looks something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/text1"
        style="@style/textStyle"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/text2"
        style="@style/textStyle"
        />
</merge>
```

My parent layout for my fragment looks something like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.mycompany.myprogram.MyCustomView
                android:id="@+id/customView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

             <SomeOtherView />

             <AnotherOtherView />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

My custom LinearLayout looks something like:

```
public class MyCustomView extends LinearLayout {

    @Bind(R.id.textView1) TextView textView1;
    @Bind(R.id.textView2) TextView textView2;

    public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initialize(context);
    }

    public ConfirmEditTextSection(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initialize(context);
    }

    private void initialize(Context context) {

        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_mycustomview, this, true);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, this);
    }
}
```

When I iterate through the child views after inflating, they are both there and marked visible. The bind also works correctly. But only one of the child views shows on the screen. The LinearLayout appears to not be matching the height of its contents; actually it is matching the height of one item but not both.

If I simply change the custom view's XML layout base-type to "LinearLayout" (rather than "merge"), then both of the child views are displayed correctly as expected. But then I have an extra LinearLayout.

To recap, when using merge, the child views are both there (and are marked visible) from within the custom class (a subclass of LinearLayout), but only one child view is showing on the screen.

Is there something extra I need to do in order to get my LinearLayout custom class to show both of its child views correctly?

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that I forgot to explicitly set the orientation.

Adding

```
setOrientation(VERTICAL);
```

just above my inflate call solved the problem.

Comment: wasted my three hours and finally applied this fix which saved me.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `android:fillViewport="true"` on the ScrollView

Usually when there is a LinearLayout inside of a ScrollView, it's not properly expanded.

```
 <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.mycompany.myprogram.MyCustomView
            android:id="@+id/customView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

        <SomeOtherView />

        <AnotherOtherView />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this didn't help (I did try it). Before using merge, I was able to successfully add elements to the LinearLayout within the ScrollView.